# PHP only deletes rows if entry is a number

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

This code is set up on a LAMP stack. I'm having trouble with the Delete page. The Delete function in PHP only works if the entry in the mysql table is a number. I need it to delete the row regardless of the entry. The email field is set up as "varchar(25)" in mysql. I don't define the variables in the code so I don't understand why it is limiting it to numbers.

Here's the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="gradientbackground">

    <table class="beachpictures" align="center" border="1">
        <thead>

        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Website</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    <?php

        require 'project_db.php';
        mysql_connect("$servername", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
        mysql_select_db("$database")or die("cannot select DB");

        //execute the SQL query and return records
        if (!$result = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM $table"))
        echo 'mysql error: ' .mysql_error();

        //fetch tha data from the database
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Email']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Website']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Gender']; ?></td>
            <td class="record-delete">
                <form action='delete.php?Email="<?php echo $row['Email']; ?>"' method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Email" value="<?php echo $row['Email']; ?>">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
   <?php }
    ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the delete.php File that performs the actual query:

```
<?php
    require 'project_db.php';
    mysql_connect("$servername", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$database")or die("cannot select DB");

//Define the query
$query = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE Email={$_POST['Email']} LIMIT 1";

//sends the query to delete the entry
mysql_query ($query);

if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
//if it updated
?>
            <strong>Record Has Been Deleted</strong><br /><br />
<?php
 } else {
//if it failed
?>
            <strong>Deletion Failed</strong><br /><br />
<?php
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add quotes: otherwise, mysql will expect $_POST['email'] to be a number.
Plus, you should switch to [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli), as `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, and you're opened to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
So your code should be:

```
<?php
    require 'project_db.php';
    $connect = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database)or die("cannot connect");

//Define the query
$query = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE Email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['Email'])."' LIMIT 1";

//sends the query to delete the entry
$execute = mysqli_query ($connect,$query);

if (mysqli_affected_rows($execute) > 0) {
//if it updated
?>
            <strong>Record Has Been Deleted</strong><br /><br />
<?php
 } else {
//if it failed
?>
            <strong>Deletion Failed</strong><br /><br />
<?php
}


?>
```

Comment: This works great!! Thank you!! The only issue left is it outputs "Deletion Failed" even though it is actually successful..

Comment: @Noor you're welcome :) It's my fault, sorry, I've updated my answer, now it should work

Comment: Thanks @Stubborn, it didn't fix it, but then I reversed the 2 statements and it works great - thank you SO much!!

Comment: @Noor I'm happy you sorted out :)